# Django Rest Framework JWT - "Error Decoding Signature" on first try only

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

As you may be able to tell from the title, I'm having an issue with [rest_framework_jwt](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/).

Strangely, right after authenticating and receiving my token, if make a follow up request using that token, and I receive a 401 Permission Denied: "Error decoding signature". I've tracked it down to an exception thrown by jwt.decode() in the jwt python library, and no variation in JWT settings resolves the issue.

The next time I make the request (same url, I just hit refresh in my app), I am verified properly and I receive a proper response.

Even more bizarre, using https://jwt.io/ and my settings.SECRET_KEY, I can verify my signature! So I know it's valid.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you reproduce it in a fresh project?

Comment: Used a little hack to get around the problem... not a real fix as problem persists, but if I wait 1ms in my app before making the request, seems to go through fine.